# change a notification sound to a tone that was picked from the tones list

Tags: android

My application has a settings activity and I have created a notification by class that extands BroadCastReceiver. In the settings activity if the user click on a button rington options list that in his phone open so the user is able to pick a tone but I need a code that will set this sound to the notification sounds.

Comment: I dont need to plat the sound

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to play the sound. If so, use this method and play your ringtone. In my case path is **/raw/notification**, you can use yours.

```
 // Playing notification sound
        public void playNotificationSound() {
            try {
                Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                        + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarmSound);
                r.play();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont need to play it

Comment: Plese help me :)

Comment: what you want to do ? please explain so i can help.

Comment: OK I have an application that has notification and in click on a Button that is in activity the user open a list with rington sounds option that is in his phone.  And I need to set the tone that was chosen to the notification that I created.